# Script to convert a shapefile to an OSM poly file on WIN 7?

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, windows-7

Is there a commande line tool running on WIN 7 which is able to create OSM poly files (polygon filter file format) from shapefiles?

The [tools listed here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Polygon_Filter_File_Format) do not seem to fit my needs. The only suitabel one seems to be ogr2poly.py. However, when I run it I recieve following error: ImportError: No module named osgeo. Actually, I'm not even sure if this script works on windows.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you may not have GDAL installed, ogr2poly.py will not work without it.

Download either the [32-bit](https://web.archive.org/web/20140730120849/http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/PackageList.aspx?file=release-1600-gdal-1-11-0-mapserver-6-4-1.zip) or [64-bit](https://web.archive.org/web/20140730115613/http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/PackageList.aspx?file=release-1600-x64-gdal-1-11-0-mapserver-6-4-1.zip) GDAL installers, depending on your system. You need to install the GDAL core, and then the GDAL Python bindings.